# startinfo.arguments question?

Tags: c#, process, arguments

I have three paths that I want to be 3 separate arguments passed into an executable. I do startinfo.arguments, but how do I separate these so the executable knows they are three different arguments?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simply pass these to the argument property with spaces separating them as you would at the command prompt, enclosing any containing spaces in double quotes.

**Update:-**

As an example of enclosing spaces in arguments, to copy 'foo bar baz.txt' to 'this is a test.txt':-

```
using (var process = new Process
       {
           StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo
           { 
               FileName = "cmd.exe",
               Arguments = "/c copy \"foo bar baz.txt\" \"this is a test.txt\""
           } 
       })
{
    process.Start();
    process.WaitForExit();
}
```

The syntax is clumsy, but has the advantage of being consistent with how you would do it at the command line, as pointed out by @Ed S.

Comment: Can you expand on the concept of enclosing containing spaces in double quotes? (Example possibly?) Thank you!\

Answer (score 1):

The argument string that you pass in should be no different than what you would pass in if you were typing into the command line.

Answer (score 1):

Lets say your program was called Test.exe and you wanted to pass it 3 command line arguments "argument1" "argument two" and "argument3"

If you were to run this from the command line you would do:

```
Text.exe argument1 "argument two" argument3
```

So your startInfo.Arguments would be set to:

```
startInfo.Arguments = "argument1 \"argument two\" argument3";
```